# How to reference libraries inside an APK, building an Android image

Tags: android, android-source, openvpn

I need to build an **Android 9 image** which includes some prebuilt **APKs** (OpenVPNForAndroid, in this specific case).

The APK, downloaded from f-droid, includes some libraries that are loaded dynamically. I've added it to the image with the Android.mk file below; the app is installed and starts normally, but fails when I try to connect with this error:

```
Cannot run program "/system/app/OpenVPNForAndroid/lib/arm64/libovpnexec.so": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/system/app/OpenVPNForAndroid/lib/arm64/libovpnexec.so": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
        at de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.startOpenVPNThreadArgs(OpenVPNThread.java:139)
        at de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.run(OpenVPNThread.java:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.VNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.VNIXProcess.<init>(VNIXProcess.java:133)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 3 more
,Error reading from output of OpenVPN process
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Process.destroy()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Process.destroy()' on a null object reference
        at de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.stopProcess(OpenVPNThread.java:56)
        at de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.startOpenVPNThreadArgs(OpenVPNThread.java:194)
        at de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.run(OpenVPNThread.java:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Apparently, the libraries that are inside of the APK are ignored.

I'd like to avoid to extract the **.so** files to add them to the image (since I fear that on future updates I'll forget to also extract the libraries again) and I think it should be possible, but apparently something is still missing.

The used Android.mk file, generated using [genandroidmk](https://github.com/northbright/genandroidmk), is this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

my_archs := arm x86 arm64
my_src_arch := $(call get-prebuilt-src-arch, $(my_archs))

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := OpenVPNForAndroid
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE_STEM := package.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := de.blinkt.openvpn_175.apk

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS := \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libjbcrypto.so \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libopenvpn.so \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libopvpnutil.so \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libosslspeedtest.so \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libovpn3.so \
  @lib/arm64-v8a/libovpnexec.so

LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := $(my_src_arch)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

and then, in my product definition I have:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += OpenVPNForAndroid
```

Am I missing something or it's simply no longer possible to refer to libraries inside an APK, without extracting them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded libs will not be extracted any more. See:
[Don't extract jni from prebuilt apks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/1fb0152ff7bf24b565b44a57e51290f2a5430107%5E%21/)

So you can extract it by LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD.
Try the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := OpenVPNForAndroid
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE_STEM := package.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := de.blinkt.openvpn_175.apk

# use lib/armeabi-v7a and lib/arm respectively, for 32bit apps
MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_SRC := lib/arm64-v8a
MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_DST := lib/arm64

ifeq ($(LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE),true)
MY_TARGET_DST := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS_PRIVILEGED)
else
MY_TARGET_DST := $(TARGET_OUT_APPS)
endif
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := unzip -o $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) $(MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_SRC)/* -d $(MY_TARGET_DST)/$(LOCAL_MODULE) ; \
    mv $(MY_TARGET_DST)/$(LOCAL_MODULE)/$(MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_SRC) $(MY_TARGET_DST)/$(LOCAL_MODULE)/$(MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_DST) ; \
    chmod 0755 $(MY_TARGET_DST)/$(LOCAL_MODULE)/$(MY_PREBUILT_LIBS_DST)/*

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I can confirm I'm on a 64 bit arch; I've tried your code, but it still doesn't work. Nothing relevant in the build logs. Any idea about how to debug this issue? Thanks.

Comment: 1. unzip -l de.blinkt.openvpn_175.apk, confirm that libovpnexec.so in inside the apk. 2. Check whether libovpnexec.so existed in /system/app/OpenVPNForAndroid/, in arm64-v8a, not arm64

Comment: 1. yes, the libraries exist inside the APK.  2. no, they are not added to the image (adding them manually, works, but that's what I'm trying to avoid).  I'm starting to think it's a limitation of Android 9; being PRESIGNED we ends up here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r61/core/prebuilt_internal.mk#378 and at that points it looks for "libs/*.so" instead of the provided list.  A lot of changes were introduced in Android 10, there (unfortunately I can't upgrade to it).  Thanks for your support!

Comment: I have modified the answer, have a look.

Comment: thanks, using LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD is a good idea.  I've edited the answer to improve it (made it more generic). Later I'll select it as the correct answer.

Comment: the only remaining problem is that after a `make dist` and signing the image, the generate system.img contains libraries with 0644 permissions, even if they were set to 0755 during the build. But that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

edit build.gradle (:app) change minSdkVersion to 21 and it working correctly, GOD may known it

```
minSdkVersion 21
```